# Unable to receive data from PHP in unity

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I have this script to interact with my database which is on mySql

```
    string dataSubmitURL = "http://localhost/HighScore/AddScore.php?";
 string dataGetURL = "http://localhost/HighScore/GetScore.php?";

       // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            StartCoroutine(GetScores());
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

        }

        IEnumerator PostScores(string playerName, int score) {
            string submitURL = dataSubmitURL + "name="+ playerName + "&score=" + score;
            print(submitURL);
            WWW submitData = new WWW(submitURL);
            yield return submitData;
            if (submitData.error != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Error occur when Submitting data : " + submitData.error);
                Debug.LogError("Error occur when Submitting data : " + submitData.text);
                Debug.LogError("Error occur when Submitting data : " + submitData.responseHeaders);
                //submitData.text
            }
            else {
                print(" Submitted");
            }

      IEnumerator GetScores() {
            WWW getData = new WWW(dataGetURL);
            yield return getData;
            if (getData.error != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("There was an error getting the high score: " + getData.error);
            }
            else {
                print(getData.text);
            }
        }
        }
```

But the problem is i am getting

> There was an error getting the high score: Empty reply from server

Although these both urls

```
 string dataSubmitURL = "http://localhost/HighScore/AddScore.php?";
 string dataGetURL = "http://localhost/HighScore/GetScore.php?";
```

working fine in browser when i directly put it. I also added this crossDomain.xml in my root folder so that it can accessible to all. What I am doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem all the code is correct and it works by changing the IP Address only.

```
string dataSubmitURL = "http://YouripAddress/HighScore/AddScore.php?";
 string dataGetURL = "http://YouripAddress/HighScore/GetScore.php?";
```